# Own Service always leads to NullPointerException in Axis2

Tags: java, glassfish, apache-axis

I am trying to create my own service from an Amazon WSDl. The step from wsdl to wsdl 2.0 to Java works fine. Even ant compiles the service without errors. After uploading the service to Axis2 all the operations are shown. But if I try to call one operation I always get the NullpointerException.

Here are the details:

```
Glassfish 3.1.2 with axis2 1.6.2 on Windows 7 64-Bit, Java 1.7.0_25 JDK
```

### HTTP-Call

```
POST /axis2/services/SimpleQueueService/CreateQueue HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
X-Amz-Date: 20130715T220823Z
User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.4.7 Windows_7/6.1 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/23.25-b01
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 17
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

QueueName=MyQueue
```

The answer is always **Internal Server Error** with the following error in the glassfish "server.log":

```
[#|2013-07-17T16:38:28.060+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=201;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[AxisServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.buildsoapMessage(BuilderUtil.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.processDocument(XFormURLEncodedBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processXMLRequest(RESTUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processXMLRequest(AxisServlet.java:826)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:227)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
|#]
```

I tried to compile the last axis2-snapshot, but glassfish did not accept it. (exceptions...)

Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that all the remote calls on the SQS WSDL take text/xml as input, not application/x-www-url-encoded. Assuming I'm looking at the same WSDL as you.

http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/QueueService.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was throwing same exception due to following missing jar's in deployment.

```
axis
jaxrpc
saaj
wsdl4j-1.5.1
commons-discovery-0.2
```

We are using axis 1.4